# Optimisation of 4D tensor rotation

Tags: arrays, math, julia, tensor

I have to perform the rotation of a 3x3x3x3 4D tensor +100k times per time step in a Stokes solver, where the rotated 4D tensor is Crot[i,j,k,l] = Crot[i,j,k,l] + Q[m,i] * Q[n,j] * Q[o,k] * Q[p,l] * C[m,n,o,p], with all indexes from 1 to 3.

So far I have naively written the following code in Julia:

```
Q    = rand(3,3)
C    = rand(3,3,3,3)
Crot = Array{Float64}(undef,3,3,3,3)
function rotation_4d!(Crot::Array{Float64,4},Q::Array{Float64,2},C::Array{Float64,4})
aux = 0.0
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:3
        for k = 1:3
            for l = 1:3

                for m = 1:3
                    for n = 1:3
                        for o = 1:3
                            for p = 1:3                                     
                                aux += Q[m,i] * Q[n,j] * Q[o,k] * Q[p,l] * C[m,n,o,p];
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end

                Crot[i,j,k,l] += aux

            end
        end
    end
end

end
```

With:

```
@btime rotation_4d(Crot,Q,C)
14.255 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Is there any way to optimise the code?

Comment: Search for Einstein summation; there seem to be `Einsum` as well as more a efficient implementation available online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I timed the various einsum packages. Einsum is faster just by virtue of adding `@inbounds`. TensorOperations is slower for such small matrices. LoopVectorization takes an age to compile here, but the end result is faster.

(I presume you meant to zero `aux` once per element, `for l = 1:3; aux = 0.0; for m = 1:3`, and I set `Crot .= 0` so as not to accumulate on top of junk.)

```
@btime rotation_4d!($Crot,$Q,$C)  # 14.556 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
Crot .= 0; # surely!
rotation_4d!(Crot,Q,C)
res = copy(Crot);

using Einsum # just adds @inbounds really
rot_ei!(Crot,Q,C) = @einsum Crot[i,j,k,l] += Q[m,i] * Q[n,j] * Q[o,k] * Q[p,l] * C[m,n,o,p]
Crot .= 0;
rot_ei!(Crot,Q,C) ≈ res # true
@btime rot_ei!($Crot,$Q,$C);      # 7.445 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

using TensorOperations # sends to BLAS
rot_to!(Crot,Q,C) = @tensor Crot[i,j,k,l] += Q[m,i] * Q[n,j] * Q[o,k] * Q[p,l] * C[m,n,o,p]
Crot .= 0; 
rot_to!(Crot,Q,C) ≈ res # true
@btime rot_to!($Crot,$Q,$C);      # 22.810 μs (106 allocations: 11.16 KiB)

using Tullio, LoopVectorization
rot_lv!(Crot,Q,C) = @tullio Crot[i,j,k,l] += Q[m,i] * Q[n,j] * Q[o,k] * Q[p,l] * C[m,n,o,p]  tensor=false
Crot .= 0; 
@time rot_lv!(Crot,Q,C) ≈ res # 50 seconds!
@btime rot_lv!($Crot,$Q,$C);      # 2.662 μs (8 allocations: 256 bytes)
```

However, this is still an awful algorithm. It's just 4 small matrix multiplications, but each one gets done many times. Doing them in series is much faster -- 9*4 * 27 multiplications, instead of [corrected!] 4 * 9^4 for the simple nesting above.

```
function rot2_ein!(Crot, Q, C)
    @einsum mid[m,n,k,l] := Q[o,k] * Q[p,l] * C[m,n,o,p]
    @einsum Crot[i,j,k,l] += Q[m,i] * Q[n,j] * mid[m,n,k,l]
end
Crot .= 0; rot2_ein!(Crot,Q,C) ≈ res # true 
@btime rot2_ein!($Crot, $Q, $C);  # 1.585 μs (2 allocations: 784 bytes)

function rot4_ein!(Crot, Q, C) # overwrites Crot without addition
    @einsum Crot[m,n,o,l] = Q[p,l] * C[m,n,o,p]
    @einsum Crot[m,n,k,l] = Q[o,k] * Crot[m,n,o,l]
    @einsum Crot[m,j,k,l] = Q[n,j] * Crot[m,n,k,l]
    @einsum Crot[i,j,k,l] = Q[m,i] * Crot[m,j,k,l]
end
rot4_ein!(Crot,Q,C) ≈ res # true
@btime rot4_ein!($Crot, $Q, $C);  # 1.006 μs
```

Comment: There's about another factor of 5 to be had by optimising the last algorithm (4 matrix multiplications), worked out in [this LoopVectorization.jl issue](https://github.com/chriselrod/LoopVectorization.jl/issues/126#issuecomment-640730139). `@btime rotation_nexpr!($Crot, $Q, $C);` gives me 183.101 ns (on the same computer as above).

Answer (score 4):

You're doing a lot of indexing here, and therefore a lot of bounds checking. One way to shave off some time here is to use the `@inbounds` macro, which turns bounds checking off. Rewriting your code as:

```
function rotation_4d!(Crot::Array{Float64,4},Q::Array{Float64,2},C::Array{Float64,4})
    aux = 0.0
    @inbounds for i = 1:3, j = 1:3, k = 1:3, l = 1:3
        for m = 1:3, n = 1:3, o = 1:3, p = 1:3                                     
            aux += Q[m,i] * Q[n,j] * Q[o,k] * Q[p,l] * C[m,n,o,p];
        end
    Crot[i,j,k,l] += aux

    end
end
```

gives me a roughly 3x speedup (6μs vs 18μs on my system).

You can read about this in the manual [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/boundscheck/). Note however that you need to make sure that all your dimensions are correctly sized, which makes working with hardcoded ranges like in your function tricky - consider using some of Julia's builtin iteration syntax (like `eachindex`) or using `size(Q, 1)` if you need your loops to change iterations numbers depending on inputs.

Answer (score 3):

That seems to be a proper contraction (every index occuring either in the output, or exactly twice on the right hand side), and thus can be done with [TensorOperations.jl](https://github.com/Jutho/TensorOperations.jl):

```
@tensor Crot[i,j,k,l] = Crot[i,j,k,l] + Q[m,i] * Q[n,j] * Q[o,k] * Q[p,l] * C[m,n,o,p]
```

Or [OMEinsum.jl](https://github.com/under-Peter/OMEinsum.jl).

It might also pay off to use [StaticArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl), since your tensor is small and of constant size.  I don't know whether it works with any Einstein summation packages, but in any case you would be able to generate a completely unrolled function for the contraction.

(Note: I didn't actually test either of them for this case.  If it is not a proper contraction, TensorOperations will complain at (I think) compile time.)